# Extract all data as files from a SharePoint instance using Powershell

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, powershell, script

I am searching for a good way to extract all uploaded files in SharePoint using `PowerShell`. I saw some options to extract all documents to .csv files, but that's not what I need.

If a user uploaded a `.txt` file I need to download it in that format only.
Is that even possible?

I am on Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Extract all data as files from a **SharePoint** or **SharePoint library** or **SharePoint list**? SharePoint would just about encompass everything?

Comment: I need the data in the *SharePoint library* thanks

Answer (score 0):

This [blog article](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/06/download-all-files-from-library-programmatically-using-powershell.html) describes the code snippet which you can use to download the files using PowerShell from SP Library.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Function to Download All Files from a SharePoint Library
Function DownloadFiles($SPFolderURL, $LocalFolderPath)
{
        #Get the Source SharePoint Folder
        $SPFolder = $web.GetFolder($SPFolderURL)


        $LocalFolderPath = Join-Path $LocalFolderPath $SPFolder.Name
        #Ensure the destination local folder exists!
        if (!(Test-Path -path $LocalFolderPath))
        {   
             #If it doesn't exists, Create
             $LocalFolder = New-Item $LocalFolderPath -type directory
        }

        #Loop through each file in the folder and download it to Destination
        foreach ($File in $SPFolder.Files)
        {
            #Download the file
            $Data = $File.OpenBinary()
        $FilePath= Join-Path $LocalFolderPath $File.Name
            [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FilePath, $data)
        }

        #Process the Sub Folders & Recursively call the function
        foreach ($SubFolder in $SPFolder.SubFolders)
        {
           if($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms") #Leave "Forms" Folder
             {
                  #Call the function Recursively
                  DownloadFiles $SubFolder $LocalFolderPath
             }
        }

    }

#Get the Source Web
$Web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/Operations"

#Get the Source SharePoint Library's Root Folder
$SourceLibrary =  $Web.Lists["Design Documents"].RootFolder

#Local Folder, where the Files to be downloaded
$DestinationPath = "C:\Test"

#Call the Download Files Function
DownloadFiles $SourceLibrary $DestinationPath
```